# Dropout is not working in train mode on Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, dropout

I am trying to do Monte Carlo sampling to estimate uncertainty. Even though I turn on the train mode by `model.train()`, dropout is not working and all the samples are getting the same value. What am I doing wrong here?

Model looks like something like below:

```
LSTM_Base(
  (lstm): LSTM(167, 256, num_layers=3, batch_first=True, dropout=0.5)
  (fc): Linear(in_features=12800, out_features=256, bias=True)
  (dropout): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
  (fc2): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=43, bias=True)
)
```

-My sampling function looks like something like this

```
def sampler(X, model, T=128):
    y_dist = []
    model.train()
    hidden_init = (torch.zeros(n_layers, 1, hidden_dim).cuda(), 
                       torch.zeros(n_layers, 1, hidden_dim).cuda())
    if model.training:
        for i in range(T):
            sample_out, _ = model.train().forward(X, hidden_init)
            y_dist.append(torch.clone(sample_out))

    return y_dist
```

Note that model is already trained, I am trying to do sampling in train mode, after I trained the model.

**EDIT**: I just realized that there is no problem about the working of train mode. Because before training, the model is able to predict different outputs in train mode. But after training with more than 10 epochs, all outputs become the same. After realizing that, I also tried to train for just one epoch, and see that outputs are different. So it is clear that the problem is not about train mode. Can it be vanishing gradients?

Comment: would you mind providing a mini script which could run your example?

Comment: I just realized that there is no problem about the working of train mode. Because before training, the model is able to predict different outputs in train mode. But after training, all outputs become the same. I also tried to train for just one epoch, and see that outputs are different. So it is clear that the problem is not about train mode. Can it be vanishing gradients?

Comment: Strange. Do weights become zero?

Comment: a subpart of lstm weight
`[ 1.3157e-02, -4.2710e-02,  1.6940e-02,  1.0987e-02,  8.9492e-03, .6779e-02,  7.3193e-02]`. Can those be considered as zero?

Comment: No, those can't be considered as zero. And a mini script is still needed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Look at the weights of the last layer, `fc2` - it might be that the weights are zeros and only the bias is non zero. Look at intermediate activations: at what layer does the outputs become constants?

Comment: Thank you @one for your valuable suggestions! unfortunately I can't share producible mini script because data is not available online. But the good thing is problem is solved after I removed the biases!

Comment: @Shai , after I removed the biases, I started getting different outputs! I guess you were right, thanks for the help!